# how to remove extra character from end of site url using htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

please help me
in have redirect in htaccess from 
http://khabarpu.com/cat/syria-news.htm#.VwHk7LGL4x4.telegram

to

http://khabarpu.com/cat/syria-news.htm

for seo i have auto delete all extra character after .htm or .php or specefic character like ==

in htaccess

Comment: Apache (which is serving your HTTP thread) does not process the hash (#) at all.

Comment: This shouldn't affect SEO. The URL fragment (`#`) just points to a section on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can see if the URL has a fragment and, if it does, then remove it:

```
$url = 'http://khabarpu.com/cat/syria-news.htm#.VwHk7LGL4x4.telegram';
$fragment = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);

// Has a fragment
if ($fragment !== null) {
    // Remove it
    $url = substr_replace($url, '', strlen($url) - strlen('#'.$fragment));
}
echo $url;
```